# Adding SimpleMarkerSymbol to InfoWindow content

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

When clicking a feature and displaying a InfoWindowLite, is there a way to add the selected feature marker from the graphic (SimpleMarkerSymbol) to the info window content?

I want to display the symbol along with the attribute used to style it on the map, e.g. :

- Type-of-feature

Comment: Isn't that possible with a custom walker function for the infoWindow?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you give me an example?
What I have done for the time being is "fake" the marker inside the infowindow by redrawing a circle of the same color using SVG. This works fine for the simple shapes like circle or box, but I don't like re-drawing something that should be accessible from the graphic already.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?